# Autocomplete in Elasticsearch with next word suggestion

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete

I want to implement autocomplete with elasticsearch and I'm unable to do it.
I want something like this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24767375/2599868). I tried the suggested answers but in vain.
I want to have something like the following :

My indexed strings are for e.g :

- "Developpeur Java"
- "Developpeur C#"
- "Je suis Developpeur"
- "Je suis écrivan"
- "Il est developpeur C++"

For input "develo", I want as output :

- "Developpeur"
- "Developpeur Java"
- "Developpeur C#"
- "Developpeur C++"

For input "developpeur", I want as output :

- "developpeur Java"
- "developpeur C#"
- "developpeur C++"

for input "suis", I want as ouput :

- "suis developpeur"
- "suis écrivan"

I tried to acheive this using completion suggester :

here's the elasticsearch I'm using :

```
"number": "6.2.2",
"build_hash": "10b1edd",
"build_date": "2018-02-16T19:01:30.685723Z",
"build_snapshot": false,
"lucene_version": "7.2.1",
"minimum_wire_compatibility_version": "5.6.0",
"minimum_index_compatibility_version": "5.0.0"
```

the mapping :

```
{
"settings": {
    "number_of_shards": "1",
    "analysis": {
        "filter": {
            "prefix_filter": {
                "type": "edge_ngram",
                "min_gram": 1,
                "max_gram": 20
            },
            "ngram_filter": {
                "type": "nGram",
                "min_gram": "3",
                "max_gram": "3"
            },
            "synonym_filter": {
                "type": "synonym",
                "synonyms": [
                    "hackwillbereplacedatindexcreation,hackwillbereplacedatindexcreation"
                ]
            },
            "french_stop": {
                "type": "stop",
                "stopwords": "french"
            }
        },
        "analyzer": {
            "word": {
                "type": "custom",
                "tokenizer": "standard",
                "filter": [
                    "lowercase",
                    "asciifolding",
                    "french_stop"
                ],
                "char_filter": []
            },
            "prefix": {
                "type": "custom",
                "tokenizer": "standard",
                "filter": [
                    "lowercase",
                    "asciifolding",
                    "synonym_filter",
                    "prefix_filter"
                ],
                "char_filter": []
            },
            "ngram_with_synonyms": {
                "type": "custom",
                "tokenizer": "standard",
                "filter": [
                    "lowercase",
                    "asciifolding",
                    "synonym_filter",
                    "ngram_filter"
                ],
                "char_filter": []
            },
            "ngram": {
                "type": "custom",
                "tokenizer": "standard",
                "filter": [
                    "lowercase",
                    "asciifolding",
                    "ngram_filter"
                ],
                "char_filter": []
            }
        }
    }
},
"mappings": {
    "training": {
        "properties": {
            "id": {
                "type": "text",
                "index": false
            },
            "label": {
                "type": "text",
                "index_options": "docs",
                "copy_to": "full_label",
                "analyzer": "word",
                "fields": {
                    "prefix": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "index_options": "docs",
                        "analyzer": "prefix",
                        "search_analyzer": "word"
                    },
                    "ngram": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "index_options": "docs",
                        "analyzer": "ngram_with_synonyms",
                        "search_analyzer": "ngram"
                    }
                }
            },
            "labelSuggest": {
                "type": "completion",
                "analyzer": "word"
            },
        }
    }
}
```

Then when I create the index with my data I do this (this is the body of the put call made to the ES api, I'm using pyhon for this):

```
body = {
    "label": r["title"],
    "labelSuggest": {
        "input": r["title"].ngrams()
    },
    "weight": 1.
}
```

r["title"].ngrams() gets all the ngrams of the title. e.g :
"Development research biotech" would give : "Development", "research", "biotech", "Development research", "research biotech" and "Development research biotech"

then to call the suggseter, I do :

```
   POST  http://localhost:9200/training/_search?pretty
{
    "suggest": {
        "labelSuggest": {
            "text": "developpeur",
            "completion": {
                "field": "labelSuggest",
                "skip_duplicates": true

            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result is :

```
{
    "text": "développement",
    "_index": "activity_20180518092449",
    "_type": "activity",
    "_id": "2031ce8b-6589-3270-afdf-7901aa21efa1",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "id": "2031ce8b-6589-3270-afdf-7901aa21efa1",
        "name": "development research biotech",
        "labelSuggest": [
            "development",
            "research",
            "biotech",
            "development research",
            "research biotech",
            "development research biotech"
        ]
    }
```

But I want something that gives me : "development", "development research" and "development research biotech" (supposing we only have that document as input)

What is wrong with the mapping/query I'm doing ?
Is-this the right way to do it ?
I hope my question is clear. I searched a lot about it in vain.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First of all teh Ngram won't do what you say.

this :

```
"ngram_filter": {
            "type": "nGram",
            "min_gram": "3",
            "max_gram": "3"
        },
```

will do this from "developpeur Java" -> dev,eve,vel,elo ... so on.

Check documentation here : [Ngram Tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html)

Second... for the result you want i will just use one custom analyzer that has filters "icu_folding" and "engram" and a whitespace tokenizer.
Now the engram i will start it from 2 and a max of 20-25.

This will generate a list of tokens like this from "developpeur Java" -> de, dev, deve, devel, develo, developp, developpe, devellopeu, developper .. so on.

Then you do a simple term search on that field. If it's a dropdown for that autocomplete you will return records as you type. 
Hope i understood your problem and  i hope this will help.

UPDATE:
Try using this :

```
"suggester": {
"type": "custom",
"tokenizer": "whitespace",
"filter": ["my_ngram_filter", "icu_folding"],
"char_filter": []
}
"my_ngram_filter" is: "my_ngram_filter": {
    "type": "edge_ngram",
    "min_gram": "2",
    "max_gram": "20"
}
```

Then mapping on the field should look like

```
"labelSuggest": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "suggester"
        }
```

Then do a simple search

```
  {
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "labelSuggest": "dev" 
    }
   }
  }
```

Comment: The ngrams() function I&#39;m using is a custom function I defined in Python.
I will try the filters and tokenizer you talked about. Thanks for your reply

Comment: I create this analyser : 
`"suggester": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": [
            "my_ngram_filter",
            "asciifolding"
          ],
          "char_filter": []
        }`
Where "my_ngram_filter" is : 
`"my_ngram_filter": {
          "type": "nGram",
          "min_gram": "2",
          "max_gram": "20"
        },`
This still doesn't work.

Comment: man... use edge_ngram. not ngram. i told you what the ngram does. also put the search part.

Comment: Yes I tried with that filter and it doen't work as I expected it.
I tried two queries : 
`{
  "query":{
   "match": {
    "labelSuggest":"dev"
    }
   }
}`
and 
`{
  "suggest": {
        "labelSuggest" : {
            "prefix" : "dev", 
            "completion" : { 
                "field" : "labelSuggest",
                "skip_duplicates": true
                
            }
        }
    }
}`
Both don't work as I expect

Comment: I expect those queries to give me the following results :
 - "Developpeur"
 - "Developpeur Java"
 - "Developpeur C#"
 - "Developpeur C++"
But they give me : 
 - "Developpeur Java"
 - "Developpeur C#"
 - "Developpeur C++"

Comment: Thanks for the more detailed answer.
I just tried that but it gives me back the whole label as result : 
It gave me  "Developpeur Java" - "Developpeur C#" - "Developpeur C++"  
It didn't give me "Developpeur" then the others as I expected

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171693/discussion-between-hamid-and-danvasiloiu).