# Look for items that a field starts with (ElasticSearch) nodejs client

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to query my ElasticSearch index in order to retrieve the items that one of the "foo" fields starts with "hel".

The toto field is a keyword type:

```
"toto": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
```

This what I tried:

```
  client.search({index: 'xxxxx',  type: 'xxxxxx_type', body: {"query": {"regexp": {"toto": "hel.*"}}}},
  function(err, resp, status) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err)
    else {
      console.log(resp);
      res.send(resp.hits.hits)
    }
  });
```

I tried to find a solution here:

> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html

and

> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_wildcard_and_regexp_queries.html

or here

> [How to search for a part of a word with ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467067/how-to-search-for-a-part-of-a-word-with-elasticsearch)

but nothing work.

This is how looks my data:

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 4,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "xxxxxx",
        "_type": "xxxxx_type",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
              "toto": "hello"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Match phrase prefix query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html) is what you are looking for.

Use the query below:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase_prefix": {
      "toto": "hel"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer I tried:
  client.search({index: 'xxxxxx',  type: 'xxxxx_type', body: {
    "query": {
      "match_phrase_prefix": {
        "toto.keyword": "hel"
      }
    }
  }},....

And empty result

Comment: from https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html it looks like this solution might not be enough: The match_phrase_prefix query is a poor-man’s autocomplete. It is very easy to use, which lets you get started quickly with search-as-you-type but its results, which usually are good enough, can sometimes be confusing.
....
For better solutions for search-as-you-type see the completion suggester and Index-Time Search-as-You-Type.

Comment: ok I found why, it works if I remove "keyword" from "toto.keyword". Thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for an auto-complete solution. running regex searches for every character the user type is not that efficient.

I would suggest changing the indexing tokenizers and analyzer in order to create the prefix tokens in advance and allow faster search.

Some options on how to implement auto complete:
Elasticsearch Completion suggester: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/search-suggesters-completion.html

or do it yourself:
https://hackernoon.com/elasticsearch-building-autocomplete-functionality-494fcf81a7cf

[How to suggest (autocomplete) next word in elastic search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24767375/how-to-suggest-autocomplete-next-word-in-elastic-search)